# R: Aggregate values (count & avg) by date and ID from separate table

Tags: r, date, aggregate

I am trying to aggregate the count and average amount of defaults from a separate table (**dataset2**) where Date2 occurred before the Date1 in **Dataset1** for each id.

Dataset1

```
Date1       ID
31.12.2013  A
31.12.2016  C
31.12.2012  S
31.12.2014  T
31.8.2015   D
31.8.2014   D
31.8.2016   H
31.8.2012   I
31.8.2013   J
```

Dataset2

```
ID  Date2         Amount         Type
A   1.2.2010       2             Default
A   1.2.2016       3             Default
C   1.4.2014       1             Default
T   1.1.2016       2             Default
D   1.1.2015       3             Default
D   1.4.2014       4             Default
H   1.9.2016       5             Default
I   1.5.2015       5             Default
J   1.5.2015       5             Default
```

Expected result:

```
Date1       ID  Count_of_defaults_before_Date2  Avg_Amount_before_date2
31.12.2013  A     1                              2
31.12.2016  C     1                              1
31.12.2012  S     0                              0
31.12.2014  T     0                              0
31.8.2015   D     2                              3.5
31.8.2014   D     1                              4
31.8.2016   H     1                              5
31.8.2012   I     0                              0
31.8.2013   J     0                              0
```

So far I have spent hours on googling for a solution, tried data.table and complex loops with If-then statements, but unfortunately with no luck. As a beginner I would really appreciate some help!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are the `ID`s always the same(ie are they the same in both data sets)? Doesn't seem to be the case in the example.

Comment: Hello! In **Dataset1** there are more unique `ID`s than in **Dataset2**. Basically, the **Dataset1** is the "master" to which the additional data is collected from **Dataset2** (if the ID can be found and `date2`s occurred before `date1`). Otherwise avg and count should be set to zero for that row. @NelsonGon

Comment: Please also note, that the same `ID` can be found on **Dataset1** with multiple different `date1`s. So the aggregation should be done on row-by-row basis. @NelsonGon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow. I tried taking a stab at this. I wasn't able to get the same results as you because either there is a data issue (the 2 dates in dataset 2 for ID "D" has are both before the 2 dates in dataset 1) or I didn't fully understand the question.

Here is my method using `dplyr`:

First, your data

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate) # dmy function

first_date <-
  data.table::fread(
    "Date1       ID
    31.12.2013  A
    31.12.2016  C
    31.12.2012  S
    31.12.2014  T
    31.8.2015   D
    31.8.2014   D
    31.8.2016   H
    31.8.2012   I
    31.8.2013   J"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(Date1 = dmy(Date1)) # converts the column into a Date class


user_defaults <-
  data.table::fread(
    "ID  Date2         Amount         Type
    A   1.2.2010       2             Default
    A   1.2.2016       3             Default
    C   1.4.2014       1             Default
    T   1.1.2016       2             Default
    D   1.5.2014       3             Default
    D   1.4.2014       4             Default
    H   1.9.2016       5             Default
    I   1.5.2015       5             Default
    J   1.5.2015       5             Default"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(Date2 = dmy(Date2))
```

Then create a dataset of some running totals

```
running_totals<-
  user_defaults %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(Date2) %>% 
  mutate(
    n_defaults = row_number(), # a running total
    avg_amount = cummean(Amount) # a cummulative mean
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Finally, do a full join then filter out some conditions to get the last line from `running_totals` prior to each `Date1`

```
running_totals%>% 
  left_join(first_date) %>% # only common column is ID so you will get all combos of Date1 & Date2
  # filter(ID == "D") %>% # you can run this to check the logic
  group_by(ID, Date1) %>% 
  filter(
    Date2 < Date1,
    n_defaults == max(n_defaults) # will be the last row before each Date1
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  full_join(first_date) %>% # used to bring in the ID/Date combos that didn't have defualts
  select(ID, Date1, n_defaults, avg_amount) %>% # put the columns in order
  arrange(ID, Date1) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, replace_na, 0) # replace NAs with 0 for the numeric columns
```

This method works fine if the data is not very big. If you have a large dataset, the `full_join` will blow up your data and eat up your memory. If this is the case, you can look into some SQL-related libraries (`SQLite`) where you can write a query like the following

```
select 
  d1.ID
  , d1.Date1
  , count(*) as n_defaults
  , mean(d2.Amount) as avg_amount
from
  dataset_1           d1
  left join dataset_2 d2 on d1.ID = d2.ID and d2.Date2 < d1.Date1  
group by
  d1.ID
  , d1.Date1
```

Comment: Thank you very much @ yake84!. First I had a lot of issues due to the fact that both, dataset1 and dataset2 had duplicate ID + DATE combinations due to slight differences in other columns not shown in the original simplified example. After these were removed this works perfectly.